# Wrong fit parameters, Undefined value during function evaluation

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to do some simple fits using Gnuplot and encountering an error which somehow I'm not able to explain. Seems that I'm doing something terribly wrong with the definition of my function.

I first started with a fit of some functions. The functional form of these is not important as the fits work pretty well, but since they are involved later I'm reporting them as well.

```
evap(x)=(x>x_fc)?A*qnet(x)/wm2_to_mmh:(x<x_wp)?0:(A*qnet(x)/wm2_to_mmh)*(x-x_wp)/(x_fc-x_wp)
fit evap(x) './fluxes_da_1p0.txt' using 1:2 via A, x_fc, x_wp

sensible(x)=( (qnet(x)/wm2_to_mmh)-evap(x) ) / (1+B)+C 
fit sensible(x) './fluxes_da_1p0.txt' using 1:3 via B,C
```

Then I defined

```
deltasensible(x)=abs(sensible(x)-sensible(0.454))
deltalatent(x)=abs(evap(x)-evap(0.454))

period_adv=18.0
g(x)=m*deltalatent(x)*period_adv*(deltasensible(x))**e
```

If I impose

```
m=3.8
e=0.5
```

and just plot the function g(x) superimposed on the data it seems to work pretty well.

However if I try to fit it using the parameters

```
fit g(x) './advection_da_1p0.txt' using 5:2 via m,e
```

I get the following error

```
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   m             e
0 4.2471983038e+00   0.00e+00  5.51e+00    3.800000e+00   5.000000e-01
1 3.7149813491e+00  -1.43e+04  5.51e-01    3.573384e+00   4.843345e-01

Current data point
=========================
#               = 8 out of 8
x               = 0.0178156
z               = 0.0309726

Current set of parameters
=========================
m               = 0.0178156
e               = -0.0583802

"rain_estimate.gpl", line 52: Undefined value during function evaluation
```

For some reason Gnuplot is trying out really strange values for m,e, although I provided their initial values. If I remove the deltalatent(x) dependency everything is working fine. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: To force positive `e`, it might help to replace it by `e = ep*ep` and `fit via ep`.

Comment: @maij Thanks for the precious suggestion. I actually found something similar here on Stackexchange and tried it out but I'm still getting issues. Gnuplot still wants a lower e... `Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
m               = 1.4648           +/- 0.1888       (12.89%)
e               = 8.26822e-05      +/- 413.7        (5.004e+08%)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured it out the problem by myself. Given my data a line was the best fit for Gnuplot so that it was trying to remove the exponential dependency on deltasensible by choosing a really small coefficient. Seems more an "error" with the data than with Gnuplot itself.